# google cloud monitoring not triggerd incident

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Metrics was over threshold.
but not trigered incidents at 2020/08/19 14:46(JST +0900) metrics.
I don't know the cause, so please help me.

Alert Policy Setting:

```
{
  "name": "projects/XXXXXXX/alertPolicies/17974723355996026588",
  "displayName": "app_more_than_error ",
  "combiner": "OR",
  ~~~~~
  "conditions": [
    {
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/app_more_than_error\" resource.type=\"gke_container\"",
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
        "thresholdValue": 0.01,
        "duration": "0s",
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        },
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM"
          }
        ]
      },
      "displayName": "logging/user/app_more_than_error [SUM]",
      "name": "projects/XXXXXXX/alertPolicies/17974723355996026588/conditions/17974723355996028427"
    }
  ],
  "notificationChannels": [
    "projects/XXXXXXX/notificationChannels/10401003724293349755"
  ],
  "enabled": true
}
```

[Image policy overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhl2o.png)

[Image incidents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I2SB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Would you review again if it is working? It is possible it was affected by some incident at GCP as per https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for Answer. But. Since it is a problem before the incident occurred, I do not think it is relevant

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the event was triggered but you did not get a notification.

I recommend reviewing the notification channel [1] documentation.

Also I share with you the document on "Alerting behavior" [2] so you may review it and the documentation on "Managing alerting policies" [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth

[3] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui

Comment: It works fine before and after the problem.  I have not received any notifications, but it has not detected an incident in Stackdriver before that.

Comment: I understand that you mean that the incident was not detected because you did not get a notification. I suggest reviewing the notification channel. [1]
---
[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options